Is the Chu-Liu/Edmond algorithm greedy in some cases?
I was learning about arborescences in graphs and came across the Chu-Liu/Edmond algorithm for finding the minimum-weight arborescence in a given directed graph.
The authors start with the premise that a greedy, Prim-like method wouldn't work in this case, and go on to explain the algorithm like this:

The first step is to create a new graph $G′$ by subtracting some
weight from each outgoing arc from a vertex, such that there is at
least one arc of weight 0. That is, set $$w(a′) ← w(a) − M_G(v)$$ for all $a ∈ ∂^+v$ and each $v ∈ V$. where $∂^+v$ is the set of edges going out of $v$.
 Now each vertex has at least one 0-weight arc leaving it. Now, for
each vertex, pick an arbitrary 0-weight arc out of it. If this choice is an arborescence, this must be the minimum-weight arborescence, since all arc weights are still nonnegative. Otherwise, the graph consist of some connected components... < material related to cycle contraction >

Let us stop right here. My question is, what does the first step even contribute? Is this simply not a greedy solution (for the part where the selection of $0$-weight edges/arcs creates an arborescence) where for each vertex $v$ we simply select any one of the minimum-weight outgoing edges from $v$?
Or is there some significance that I miss?
